# While iterating over a mutable HashMap in for expresssion, referencing to map in ennumarator changes value obtained in loop body

Tags: scala

I would start with example then explain the problem I see:

```scala
object Example extends App {

  val arr = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

  import scala.collection.mutable
  val countMap = new mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int, Int] ++ arr.map(_ -> 1)

  for {
    (idx, count) <- countMap
    // _ = idx + 1
  } {
    (idx + 1 to 4) foreach { i =>
      countMap(i) += 3
    }
    println(s"$idx $count")
  }
}
```

In the above code I create a mutable `HashMap` (made it `LinkedHashMap` to print in order) Where each entry is initialized to `1`. and in a loop and modify some entries in the Hashmap, which are referred later in the loop. The `println` statement print the values are they are updated.

But if I uncomment the line `_ = idx + 1` I do not see the updated counts printed. Instead all the counts are printed as initialized value of `1`.

I do not understand why this behavior exists?

P.S.

1. The final value of the map is updated to the same state regardless.
2. I see same behavior in Scala 3

```scala
object Blah extends App:
  import scala.collection.mutable
  val arr = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

  val countMap = new mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int, Int] ++ arr.map(_ -> 1)

  for
    (idx, count) <- countMap.view
    _ = idx + 1
  do
    (idx + 1 to 4) foreach { i =>
      countMap(i) += 3
    }
    println(s"$idx $count")
```

Comment: While being slightly surprising, I think no one should be writing such code in the 1st place in Scala. It's hard to read and understand. Try to use only immutable data in Scala.

Comment: Its true, but depending on solution its performant and readable to write to with mutability that to dance around with immutable structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for-comprehension is syntactical sugar for `foreach`, `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` methods. So you have to look at your program in the above terms.

So following `for` becomes just a simple `foreach`

```scala
for {
  (idx, count) <- countMap
} {
  ???
}

// is equivalent to

countMap.foreach { case (idx, count) => ??? }
```

Now, once you add a `_ = idx + 1` it does impact how for comprehension is transformed.

```scala
for {
  (idx, count) <- countMap
  _ = idx + 1
} {
  ???
}

// is equivalent to

countMap
  .map { case (idx, count) => val _ = idx + 1; (idx, count) }
  .foreach { case (idx, count) => ??? }
```

Now you have a `map` method added before the final call of `foreach`. `map` method converts the whole `countMap` into a new collection with each element copied over into a new collection. Once this collection is created, the body of `foreach` method is called.

You can "solve" the problem by writing `for` over `countMap.view`, which prevents a new collection to be created.

```scala
for {
  (idx, count) <- countMap.view
  _ = idx + 1
} {
  (idx + 1 to 4) foreach { i =>
    countMap(i) += 3
  }
  println(s"$idx $count")
}
```

Final remark, scala promotes immutability by default. Even though there are mutable collections, they must be used with care. And furthermore, one should not be mutating collections when traversing them. This brings to such undesired and hidden (mis)behaviours of programs.